# IQueryable Evaluation

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, lazy-evaluation

I'm new to EF/Linq-To-SQL. I read on SO previously that IQueryable is beneficial over IEnumerable in that it does lazy evaluation. Concerning the following simple example:

```
var records = db.Employees.Where(x => x.EmployeeID == "3" );

if (records.Any())
{
     var topRecord = records.First();
}
```

Is the IQueryable expression being evaluated twice? Once to check for any elements in the result set, and once when retrieving the first element? If so, is there a more efficient way to peform such a select?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in this case the query will be executed twice: firstly for `Any` and then for `First`.

You could probably use [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357733.aspx) instead:

```
var topRecord = db.Employees.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmployeeID == "3" );
// topRecord will be null if there's no match

if (topRecord != null)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: +1: Deleted my (incorrect) answer. I glossed right over the evaluation to boolean at `Any`.

Comment: @LukeH edited your post to point out in which case FirstOrDefault would help to only have one query execution